# Compartilhar evento de botão entre componentes em um projeto Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso de uma orientação por favor, tenho uma estrutura de componentes em um projeto Angular:

1) Componente Cabecalho

2) Componente Corpo e dentro deste o Componente Rodape

O botão existente dentro do componente Cabecalho precisa exibir/ocultar as `<div>` que estão dentro dos demais componentes, no caso a  `<div class="card"></div>` e a `<div class="footer></div>`.

Exemplo:

Componente Cabecalho.html:

```html
<button (click)="toggleShow()">Esconder / Exibir</button>
```

Componente Cabecalho.ts:

```js
isShown: boolean = false;


toggleShow() {

this.isShown = ! this.isShown;

}
```

Componente Corpo.html:

```html
<div class="card" *ngIf="isShown">
  <p>Conteúdo</p>
</div>
```

E dentro do Componente Corpo o Componente Rodape:

```html
<div class='footer' *ngIf="isShown">
  <p>&COPY;</p>
</div>
```

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Não sabemos como está a hierarquia das suas pastas no projeto, mas, dependendo dá para usar **eventEmitter()** ,ou, o mais indicado que seria um service.

Comment: Eu tentei usar o eventEmitter(), mas sou novato no Angular, não consegui entender como aplicar ainda. Você poderia me ajudar? A estrutura das pastas e como descrevi acima: cabecalho, corpo e dentro do corpo Rodape. Obrigado.

Comment: O componente cabecalho não é pai dos outros componentes logo eventEmitter não vai funcionar terá que fazer isso utilizando um service.

Comment: Sim, o cabecalho não é o pai, ele é irmão do componente corpo, já o componente rodape é filho do componente corpo, a melhor solução seria um service? pode me ajudar?

Comment: Então eu to apertado aqui no trampo hj mas dá uma pesquisada em **behaviorSubject**, esse link é muito bom e em português dá pra entender legal, se seguir os passos ali provavelmente conseguirá fazer o que quer: https://medium.com/xp-inc/compartilhamento-de-dados-angular-4-fc1218c50a99

Comment: Obrigado LeAndrade

Comment: Conseguiu resolver aí Munir?

Comment: Opa LeAndrade, tudo bem? Na verdade ainda não, estava tentando usar o decorator @input, você consegue me dar uma força utilizando esse recurso?

Comment: Com @Input não vai funcionar pq são componentes irmãos e não filho um do outro a não ser corpo e rodapé, mas, pq não conseguiu utilizando service? Aquele link passa td que precisa!

Answer (score 0):

Como o componente cabeçalho não é pai dos outros componentes, o recomendado é utilizar o [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) em um service do angular.

**Criando um service**

Você irá precisar criar um novo [service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) para o cabeçalho, você pode optar por criar um manualmente:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class CabecalhoService {

  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  data = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updateToggle(toggle: boolean) {
    this.dataSource.next(toggle);
  }
```

ou você pode usar os comandos do AngularCLI: ng generate service cabecalho e adicionar o BehaviorSubject;
Logo após você deverá inserir esse service no seu module:

```
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [CabecalhoService]
  ...
})
...
```

**Modo de uso**

Agora que você já tem o service você deverá "chamá-lo" nos componentes que você deseja utilizar:

```
constructor(
    ...
    private cabecalhoService: CabecalhoService
  ) { }
```

Agora você pode utilizar o seu componente, iremos começar pelo componente do cabeçalho.
no seu método "toggleShow(...)":

```
this.cabecalhoService.updateToggle(this.isShown);
```

E pronto, seu cabeçalho já está enviando os dados para o service, agora nos componentes que você deve utilizar:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.cabecalhoService.data.subscribe(data => {
  // faça o que for necessário quando os dados forem alterados
  })
}
```

Você pode aprender mais sobre services do angular no [Tour of Heroes do angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), entretanto lá não utilizam o BehaviorSubject.

Comment: Obrigado mtwzim! Vou tentar implementar desta forma.